# How did an assember for x86 get a label's address defined after jmp instructions referenced to it?

Tags: assembly, x86

For example:

```
jmp LABEL

...  # loads of instructions

jmp LABEL

.... # loads of instructions

LABEL:

.....
```

Without the size of `jmp LABEL` instruction, the address of LABEL can't be determine because the two forms of jmp instruction (short (2 Bytes), near (3 or 5 Bytes)) have different size. Whereas, without knowing about LABEL's address, you cannot determine which form to use.

How does assembler solve it?

Comment: Logically, assembling code is a multi-phase operation. The address of labels will not be resolved until all other code is generated. So the size of all the encoded instructions between `jmp` and `LABEL` will be known.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the kind of assembler you use.  A simple 2-pass assembler (like MASM) makes it your problem.  They'll pick a long jump and you have to write `JMP SHORT LABEL` explicitly to get the short one.  And bitch at you when you guessed wrong.

An optimizing n-pass assembler (like TASM) sorts it out by itself.  It assumes the short jump and if it discovers that it can't reach then it restarts the assembly, now with a long jump.

You can easily tell what kind of flavor you have.  Just look at the code listing it generates, if you get the 5 byte long jump then you have the 2-pass kind.

Comment: Older versions of `nasm` used to always go with the long `jmp`, while `yasm` was smart enough to go with the short `jmp` - although `nasm` may be better now.

Comment: And don't forget FASM which is the most advanced multipass assembler ever made. It always generates the smallest possible opcode.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use 5 bytes (opcode + far address) so this is what assembler does initialy.
After then it runs (possibly multiple times) reduction algorithm to see if it can improve the code. Once it sees no improvement is possible it stops and code is done.